# Get rows that are referenced in another table

Tags: postgresql

I have two entities. **`product`** and **`bom`**.

```
CREATE TABLE product (
  id integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT product_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

/* Bill of materials*/
CREATE TABLE bom (
  id serial NOT NULL,
  parent_item_id integer NOT NULL,
  child_item_id integer NOT NULL,
  quantity integer NOT NULL
)
```

The entity **`product`** register single products and composite products (products made up of other products). The products that are composite, are referenced in the entity **`bom`** through `parent_item_id` and `child_item_id`.

I am using this structure because I can create composite products made of other composite products.

Now, What I want is to perform a **SELECT** that return all the products that are composed of another products.

More specifically, the records in the product table that are referenced in the table **`bom`** through **`product.id`** and **`bom.parent_item_id`**.

So far I have the next SQL code:

```
SELECT product.id
FROM product
INNER JOIN bom ON product.id = bom.parent_item_id;
```

My problem is that this JOIN give me duplicate product entries, obviously because `product.id` appears in **`bom`** as many product is made of.

I want just one entry per product that is referenced in **`bom`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds as if you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT product.id
FROM product
where exists (select *
              from bom 
              where bom.parent_item_id = product.id);
```

Alternatively

```
SELECT id
FROM product
where id in (select parent_item_id
             from bom);
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks for the quick response.